# Case-Insensitive String Comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to show the MsgBox if those two strings are equal but doesn't look at upper- or lowercase.

```
For teller = 1 To 51
If Cells(teller, 5).Value = Me.txtGebruikersnaam Then
    MsgBox ("Deze Gebruiker bestaat al!")
    Exit Sub
    Else
End If
Next
```

I tried to use:

```
If (StrComp(Cells(teller, 5).Value = Me.txtGebruikersnaam, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: By the way, you do not need the extra set of parentheses around the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Please try:

```
If LCase$(Cells(teller, 5).Value) = LCase$(Me.txtGebruikersnaam) Then
```

Comment: Do you force the `Cells()` to a string, because `Cells(teller,5).Value` may not be a string, and this forces it to be a string so `LCase()` works?  Do you get errors if you just left it `If LCase(Cells(teller, 5).Value) ...`?

Comment: No. OP says he is comparing two strings and trying to ignore case. Quick way is to force both strings to either upper or lower case and compare the results. If either is numeric, it will be cast to a string and then the LCase$() works on the string, which of course does nothing to numeral characters.

Answer (score 4):

You actually have a subtle bug in your usage of StrComp.

The code in the original post states:

```
If (StrComp(Cells(teller, 5).Value = Me.txtGebruikersnaam, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
```

The problem is that you have a typo, and meant to write:

```
If StrComp(Cells(teller, 5).Value, Me.txtGebruikersnaam, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

The subtlety is that `Cells(teller, 5).Value = Me.txtGebruikersnaam` will evaluate to `False/0` unless you have a perfect case sensitive match, and then get compared to `vbTextCompare`, which is a predefined constant with value 1.

Try it with a comma rather than an equals.

PS: Also removing extra brackets as pointed out by Excel Hero.